# jQuery.ajax()で外部HTMLファイルを読み込んで要素を取得したい

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

jQuery.ajax()で外部HTMLファイルを読み込んで要素を取得したいのですが、
find, filter関数でid名やクラス名を指定しても取得できません。どうしたら良いのでしょうか？
ちなみに、同じクラス名をもつ複数の要素も配列で取得したいです。

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://yahoo.co.jp',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(res) {
        var data = $(res)[0].responseText; //文字列で取得できています

        var content = $(res.responseText).find('id名').text(); //取得できません
        console.log(content);  

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: 「取得できません」とのことですが、console.log(content)で何が出力されるのでしょうか？ そもそも、サーバ側が許可しない限りajaxで外部ドメインの内容は取得できないので、successまで来るのかさえ疑問なのですが・・・？

Comment: console.log(content)では、何も出力されません。
jquery.xdomainajax.jsというjQueryライブラリを使用しています。console.log(data)では、http://yahoo.co.jp のhtmlが文字列で出力されます。

Comment: successではなくてerrorでデバックしてのその結果「console.log(data)」を貼り付けてください。[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: error関数のコードを追加しましたが、error関数には入らず、success関数に入ります。

Comment: `id名`って具体的に何でしょうか？ ひょっとして#が抜けてるとか？？

Comment: 試験的に("#dsearch")と指定したのですが、何も出力されません。

Comment: 外部HTMLファイルには本当に当該idが記述されていることは確認されましたか？ JavaScriptで動的に生成されるもので外部HTMLファイル自体には記述されていないということはありませんか？ 可能であれば取得している正確なURLを提示してください。

Answer (score 1):

jquery.xdomainajax.js＋サンプルコードで試したわけではないですが、ブラウザでyahooのソースを表示、コピーして試してみたところ、たしかに取得できない事象に遭遇しました。

原因ですが、帰ってきたレスポンスHTMLを、そのまま`$(レスポンスHTML)`というふうにjQuery関数に渡しても、正しくjQueryオブジェクトに変換できないようです。原因はHTMLの一行目にある以下の記述だと思われます。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

jQueryはxmlをパースできないので、この文が悪さしているようです。
試しにこの行を削ってみると上手くいきました。

```
var $jq = $(レスポンスHTML.replace('<!DOCTYPE[^>]+>', ''))
$jq.find('#dsearch').text() //=> "辞書"
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。無事取得できました。
ご丁寧に解説していただき、本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

.parseHTML()と .filter() を使うとどうでしょう？

```js
        $(function(){
            var str1 = '';
            str1 += '<html>';
            str1 += '<body>';
            str1 +=     '<h1>test</h1>';
            str1 +=     '<div id="hoge"  style="background-color: chartreuse">こ れそれあれ</div>';
            str1 += '<div>hoge</div>';
            str1 += '</body>';
            str1 += '</html>';
            var jq_obj = $($.parseHTML(str1));
            $("#data").append(jq_obj.filter("#hoge"));
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="data">

</body>
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
jquery 1.11.1を指定すると以下のようなエラーが出てしまい、文字列も
取得できなくなってしまいました。

XMLHttpRequest : 200  index.html:33:5
textStatus     : parsererror  index.html:34:5
errorThrown    : jQuery111102971448765310516_1508458631598 was not called